# How to get the string values from try catch statement without using textview in android?

Tags: java, android, json, text, try-catch

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        TextView lattv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
        TextView lngtv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
        JSONParstring jParser = new JSONParstring();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        // getting JSON string from URL

        try
        {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);

            res = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
            for(int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = res.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject loc = c.optJSONObject(TAG_GEO).optJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);

            String lat =loc.getString(TAG_LAT);

            String lng = loc.getString(TAG_LNG);

            lattv.setText(lat);
            lngtv.setText(lng);
            Log.i("Lat",lat);

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){ }
        String i=(String) lattv.getText();
        String j=(String) lngtv.getText();

        double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(i);  
        double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(j);
```

Here inside my try catch statment,i am getting the latitude and longtitude value instead of getting directly, i use textview then i convert into string format.i wanna to get the two values directly from try catch statment.is this possbile?

Comment: Is *what* possible? What's your question? Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please try below code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
TextView lattv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
TextView lngtv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
JSONParstring jParser = new JSONParstring();
String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
// getting JSON string from URL
String lat ="",lng="";
try
{
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);

    res = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = res.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject loc = c.optJSONObject(TAG_GEO).optJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);

    lat =loc.getString(TAG_LAT);

    lng = loc.getString(TAG_LNG);

    //lattv.setText(lat);
    //lngtv.setText(lng);
    Log.i("Lat",lat);

    }
}
catch (JSONException e){ }
//String i=(String) lattv.getText();
//String j=(String) lngtv.getText();

double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);  
double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(lng);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `lat` and `lng` outside the `try catch` block, you may modify its values inside the `try catch` block and access it outside the `try catch` block

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your variables directly in the try/catch block :

```
double lat1;
double lng1;

try
{
    // ...
    lat1 = Double.parseDouble(loc.getString(TAG_LAT));
    lng1 = Double.parseDouble(loc.getString(TAG_LNG));
}
```

Comment: here i couldnt be used,we call directly double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);   shall i put like this?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer. You don't even need to use two temporary String variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to declare your String lat and lng outside the try catch.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);


      String lat = null;

        String lng = null;

    JSONParstring jParser = new JSONParstring();
    String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    // getting JSON string from URL

    try
    {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);

        res = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = res.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject loc = c.optJSONObject(TAG_GEO).optJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);

        lat =loc.getString(TAG_LAT);

        lng = loc.getString(TAG_LNG);

        lattv.setText(lat);
        lngtv.setText(lng);
        Log.i("Lat",lat);

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e){ }

    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat );  
    double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(lng );
```